# What do I call this "cogwheel" that feeds tin cans to a specific position?

Tags: terminology

This is an above view of a system in which tin cans arrive via conveyor (1) to a "feeding star" ("**подающая звезда**" in Russian; No. 5) and are placed firmly in slot 4. ([source in Russian](http://www.freepm.ru/Models/105263.html))

[image]

What does one call this "feeding star" in English?

I'm actually translating a text about a pharmaceutical filling-and-capping line, in which there is a "feeding star" and a "stoppering star". My text comes with no drawings, but I googled and found out that these "stars" are basically star-like cogwheels that take something from a moving conveyor system and position it precisely for further use. In my text, this "feeding star" probably passes drug-filled vials to the "stoppering star" which is part of the vacuum-operated automatic stoppering unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it may be called **starwheel feeder** or **starwheel infeed** - here's an excerpt from *[Design of Automatic Machinery](https://goo.gl/A2FRG3):*

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Sprocket is one possibility, a feed or delivery spider are other possibilities.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12764)

Comment: @peterh I don't have a question - these are possible options for the op to use for his translation as prr his question ...... or, is your script making wide sweeping assumptions....

Comment: This comment doesn't seem like a question at all. I also think it's a pretty appropriate answer given the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The "feeding" and "stoppering" seem to be just literal Russian-to-English translations of "filling" and "capping," which would be good technical terms in English.

I would call the "star" an "escapement" by analogy with mechanical clocks etc - it forces the cans to move one at a time in a controlled manner, in the same way that at clockwork escapement allows a gear wheel to move one tooth at a time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nhNu-AlAfo

"Escapement" seems to be used in this context in several US patents for can filling devices that operate on one can at a time, though I couldn't find one that used the same "star" type of device.